# Prove $ a: H_1 × H_2 \rightarrow H_1 + H_2 $ is an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-sum

I want to know that how to prove the following proposition:

Given an abelian group $G$, if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are any subgroups of $G$ such that $H_1 \cap H_2 = \{0\}$, then the map $a$ is an isomorphism
$$
a: H_1 × H_2 \rightarrow H_1 + H_2
$$

Actually, I have got that the kernel of map a is $\{0,0\}$. $\forall a \in H_1, \ \forall b \in H_2$, then we have $H_1 × H_2$ is direct product which means $a × b \in H_1 × H_2$, besides, $H_1 + H_2$ is direct sum which means $a + b \in H_1 + H_2$

Comment: What have you tried? What is the image of $a$? What is its kernel?

Comment: I think the kernel of map a is $\{0,0\}$.

Comment: If you can prove that, that means $a$ is injective. Can you show that it is surjective?

Comment: Actually, I wonder if the map satisfies surjective. Could you prove that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the definition of $H_1 + H_2$? What does an element of $H_1 + H_2$ look like?

Comment: For any element in group $H_1$ such that $\forall a \in H_1$ and any element in group $H_2$ such that $\forall b \in H_2$, then we have $a+b \in H_1+H_2$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your definition. I would usually say $H_1 + H_2 = \{h \in G \mid h= h_1 + h_2 \text{ for some } h_1 \in H_1 \text{ and } h_2 \in H_2\}$. Do you see how to finish your proof?

Comment: @Divide 1918 has answered this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $h\in H_1+H_2$, then $h=h_1+h_2$ for some $h_1\in H_1,h_2\in H_2$. Hence every $h\in H_1+H_2$ can be mapped from $h_1h_2\in H_1 × H_2$, which means $a: H_1 × H_2 \rightarrow H_1 + H_2$ is indeed surjective.

Comment: Your answer is so helpful for me, thanks a lot!